# Redirect Domain to Subdomain using Cloudflare

Tags: redirect, dns, http-headers, cloudflare

I'm using a marketing automation platform to build landing pages and those landing pages URLS are automatically published with a subdomain structure, like:

https://subdomain.example.com/mylandingpage

I want to redirect all www and non www visits to the main domain to this landing page that I created, in other words I wish the https://example.com and https://www.example.comto be redirected to https://subdomain.example.com/mylandingpage

Since I'm only using this platform and did not subscribe to any hosting, I'm trying to use Cloudflare to make all this redirects.

I saw a tutorial and this guy said that A entries in my DNS shouldn't be blank and recommended setting them to a reserved IP address, so I set both A entries to 192.0.2.0.

Ok, then I went to page rules and set a 301 redirect to *example.com to be redirected to https://subdomain.example.com/mylandingpage

I can see that when I visit my main domain it's redirected to the subdomain correctly, but the page doesn't load, and I get a too many redirections error. I believe that I made something wrong and it's redirecting everything to the subdomain, even the subdomain is redirecting to itself, even having a page path /mylandingpage after the hostname.

Did I make myself clear? Is there any other way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

In Cloudflare page rules instead of *.example.com, please use exact domain match.

URL path we can use wildcard.

[www.example.com/](http://www.example.com/)*  - https://subdomain.example.com/mylandingpage
example.com/* - https://subdomain.example.com/mylandingpage